# Can a child element pass validation issues up to the <DataAnnotationsValidator> in the parent

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm reducing this down to the essentials. If I reduced too much, please ask for detail.

I have a razor page as follows:

```
<EditForm>
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  <AddressForm @ref="_addressElement"
       Value="@Model.AddressForm"
       ValueChanged="OnAddressSelected">
  </AddressForm>
  <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

And here is AddressForm.razor

```
<DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Model.StreetNumberAndName" ShowValidationIcon="true" />
```

And here is it's model property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your street address is required")]
public string? StreetNumberAndName
{
    get => _streetNumberAndName;
    set => _streetNumberAndName = value?.Trim();
}
```

Here's my question. How can I get the `[Required]` validation messages up/out of `<AddressForm>` and to the `<DataAnnotationsValidator>` in the parent razor/component?

Comment: I don't think you can.  I'm assuming here you have a complex data object that you are trying to edit - something like a `Person` object that contains an `Address` object?  If so there are different ways to approach the editing of such an object.  I can add a bit of a discussion as an answer of you want.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I asked on MSDN and was pointed to a really useful library that does this (see answer below). It makes it all super easy.

Comment: Yes, I know about that.  Note it's "experimental", and has been for a long time, which sort of suggests that it isn't ever going to be a fully supported library.  I suspect it's there for people who have got to your point and need an answer that isn't re-design your application.  I'll accept that's a somewhat bigoted view, but ... I'm guessing not many pros use it!

Comment: I'm not a fan of the whole object graph concept, so don't use it.  You will see examples of people loading their whole application into a data graph, then manipulating and saving it:  Crazy Ivan idea in my book.  I use simple data backends and complex objects are dealt with as Aggregates which use transactional unit of work contexts to write their data back to the data store.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree with you - usually. But this is a really clean and simple solution to this problem. And any other solution was going to be complex. So I'll take this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hat tip to Zhi Lv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1301030/can-a-child-element-pass-validation-issues-up-to-t) who gave me this. This is all from him - he deserves the credit for this.

To validate the bound model's entire object graph, including collection- and complex-type properties, use the ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator provided by the experimental Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation package (Note: you need to checked the "include prerelease" option if you want to install this package via "Manage Nuget Package..." ).

Refer to the following sample:

Model: Note: we are using the ValidateComplexType attribute for the navigation property.

```
public class TestModel
    {
        [Required (ErrorMessage ="Please enter the Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public AddressViewModel AddressForm { get; set; }
    }
    public class AddressViewModel
    { 
        private string _streetNumberAndName;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your street address is required")]
        public string? StreetNumberAndName
        {
            get => _streetNumberAndName;
            set => _streetNumberAndName = value?.Trim();
        }
    }
```

Parent component: using ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator instead of DataAnnotationsValidator.

```
@page "/testpage"
@using BlazorServerApp3.Data

<EditForm Model="Model">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <AddressForm @ref="_addressElement" testModel="Model"></AddressForm>
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="mt-n2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code{
    TestModel Model = new TestModel() { AddressForm= new AddressViewModel()};
    AddressForm _addressElement;  
}
```

Child Component:

```
@using BlazorServerApp3.Data;
<h3>AddressForm</h3>

<input type="text" @bind="testModel.Name" />
<input type="text" @bind="testModel.AddressForm.StreetNumberAndName" />
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TestModel testModel { get; set; }
}
```